# Get hold of product review summary in Magento

Tags: magento

I'd like to get hold of a product's Rating Score (e.g. 4 out of 5) and number of reviews the product has. I can get hold of the number of reviews, but not the rating score.

I'm doing this from my event observer class:

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(); // returns 1

$productId = $product->getId(); // returns 135

$summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($productId); // returns 

$reviewsCount = $summaryData->getReviewsCount();  // this works

$ratingSummary = $summaryData->getRatingSummary(); // this does not return the rating score I had hoped it would. It just returns a blank string.
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Your code tested on Magento 1.4.2, 1.5.1 and 1.6.1 works as expected.
The only difference to your code is that I hardcode the store ID and the product id.
A loop over all products with a review works as well, too:

```
<?php
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
foreach ($products as $product)
{
    $summary = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId())
            ->load($product->getId());
    if ($summary->getId())
    {
        echo $summary->getRatingSummary() . "\n";
    }
}
```

Have you checked the expected results in the `review_entity_summary` table for the entity 135?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling reviews code in a loop? If so take a look at `_initReviewsHelperBlock` method in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` class. It returns false when initialized for the second time

Still to confirm this is a bug, but had to rewrite the class in the `local` pool

Comment: thank you for replying. I an going through the cart and calling the above code for each product in the cart. getRatingSummary returns nothing for all the products. I am using version 1.4.2.0 of Magento. Are you able to confirm if there is anything wrong with the code I have written or if in fact this is a bug?   Anyone else out there experiencing this same problem?

Comment: I believe the helper wasn't intended to be used in a loop. Not sure it's a bug or a design flaw. Probably there is a way to initialize it in a different way